# (fresh angular project) main.js files size is increased when I import modules into isolated feature module

Tags: angular

I have a fresh angular project with 3 modules. `AppModule`, `CoreModule` and `TestModule`.

1. `CoreModule` and `TestModule` are no way related or imported to `AppModule`.
2. `CoreModule` lazy loads `TestModule`

[github link](https://github.com/goodmite/angular-hello-world-size-too-big)
[image]

**Problem:**

If I import any Modules (like `HttpClientModule` etc.) to `TestModule`, size of `main.js` file increased. My understanding is that only the content of `AppModule` should affect size of `main.js` and not any feature module (`TestModule`).

In `TestModule`, if you comment Module imports, `main.js` size = 182kb (= 51kb gzip) after `ng build --prod`

In `TestModule`, if you uncomment Module imports, `main.js` size = 195kb (= 54.6kb gzip) after `ng build --prod`

Code:

**AppModule**

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

**CoreModule**

```
import {Route, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {CoreWrapperComponent} from './core-wrapper.component';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';


const routes: Route[] = [
  {

    path: '',
    component: CoreWrapperComponent,
    children: [{
      path: 'test', loadChildren: './test.module#TestModule', canLoad: []
    }],
  },
  {path: '', redirectTo: `core/viewbots/test`, pathMatch: 'full'},
];

declare let areReducersRegistered;

@NgModule({
  declarations: [CoreWrapperComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
  ],
  providers: []
})
export class CoreModule {
}
```

**TestModule**

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {Route, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

const routes: Route[] = [];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,

    /*
    * If you comment following Module main.js size = 182kb (= 51kb gzip)
    * If you uncomment following Module main.js size = 195kb (= 54.6kb gzip)
    *
    * Since TestModule is not imported in AppModule in any way, adding or removing modules
    * in TestModule should have no impact on main.js file size
    * */
    // RouterModule,
    // HttpClientModule,
    // FormsModule,
    // ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
})
export class TestModule {
}
```

Comment: Mmmh, did you check with Webpack Bundle Analyzer?

Comment: I kind of got the answer here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/32808#issuecomment-534459996